# При входе на сайте через андроид предлагать скачать с play market

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, css

При входе на сайте через андроид смартфон, планшет предлагать скачать приложение  с play market-а , как такое можно реализовать можете примерчик показать.
буду весьма признателен....

Comment: проверить UserAgent в запросе видимо?

Answer (score 3):

примерчик:

```
if(mb_stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false){
    echo "wow!"
}
```

для js

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0){
   //wow 
}
```

Comment: То ли ТС переборщил с тегами, то ли ожидается и вариант с проверкой на фронте

Comment: @br3t может и так